# Undocumented, mysterious class--rubbish, or a design pattern I don't know?

Tags: java, swing

I inherited the following code:

(Some names are changed to protect the innocent.)

```
package foo.bar.baz;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

//Main panel in the GUI
class DemoRootPanel extends JPanel {
    private final MainGUIClass demo;

    DemoRootPanel(MainGUIClass demo) {
        super();   
        this.demo = demo;
    }

    public MainGUIClass getDragAndDropPanelsDemo() {
        return demo;
    }
}
```

I didn't immediately see why it was important, so I grepped through the source tree to see it being used. These are all the results:

```
$ ack -i rootpanel
DemoRootPanel.java
5:class DemoRootPanel extends JPanel {
8:    DemoRootPanel(MainGUIClass demo) {

MainGUIClass.java
70: private final DemoRootPanel rootPanel;
124:        rootPanel = new DemoRootPanel(MainGUIClass.this);
821:                    containerPanels.add(new ContainerPanel(rootPanel));
846:                            containerPanels.add(new ContainerPanel(rootPanel));
1777:               ContainerPanel newContainer = new ContainerPanel(rootPanel);

ContainerPanel.java
30: DemoRootPanel rootPanel;
49: public ContainerPanel(DemoRootPanel rootPanel) {
51:     this.rootPanel = rootPanel;
```

and

```
$ ack getDragAndDropPanelsDemo
DemoRootPanel.java
13:    public PileSortGUI getDragAndDropPanelsDemo() {
```

So as far as I see, it's completely unnecessary. But this is my first job, I haven't been to college yet, etcetera, so I'm wondering if it's not some idiom that's important but unfamiliar to me.

*PS - I'm also relatively new to SO. I believe this question can be answered definitively, but it does seem less technical than normal. If it's not okay, let me know and I'll take it down. (Or just mod it :P )*

Comment: `"I didn't immediately see why it was important"`, `"So as far as I see, it's completely unnecessary"` What's is the *it* that you are referring to?

Comment: DemoRootPanel.java--the entire class.

Comment: without seeing the code to `MainGUIClass` it is indeterminate what the intention was. Does `MainGUIClass` inherit from something that can be put into `ContainerPanel`?

Comment: Obviously it's being used in the constructor for `ContainerPanel` class so you cannot just delete the class. Whether you can eliminate the class or not mostly depends on the architecture and design for your software.

Comment: `MainGUIClass` extends `JFrame` and is the main window. It contains several panels, one of which contains many `ContainerPanel`s. @Bala I see that it's used in the constructor of `ContainerPanel`, but I also see that `ContainerPanel` never uses it. As far as I see, the reason to use `DemoRootPanel` is to have a `JPanel` with access to `MainGUIClass`--except any component I use already has access with repeated application of `getParent()`. \n I'm just worried that it was built with an eye to the future, and I just don't see (yet) how it will be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is just an empty JPanel which additionally contains a reference to an object of the main class.

It could be that this could be simply replaced by a plain `JPanel` (ommiting the `demo` argument).

It could be that someone planned to used this class for some goal but forgot this later. Or someone misunderstood and thought that every GUI object one uses must have an own subclass. The comment `//Main panel in the GUI` looks like this.

If you have someone who wrote this code, ask him (or her) - otherwise I would just replace its use with a simple JPanel to cut down the number of classes. (You have a version control system, don't you?)

Comment: Those sound like plausible theories. All the previous developers are gone, so I'll just remove that class and trust svn, like you suggested. Thanks.